# can I scan for ibeacon using android 4.1 device

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon

put aside the power consumption issue, is that possible for an android 4.1 device using classic bluetooth to scan for ibeacon?

if possible, sample code is much appreciated.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: **NO**

Long(er) answer: The [BluetoothLeScanner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html) was added in API level 21 (Android 5.0) and Android 4.1 is API level 16.